# Delaying function calling - Python

Tags: function, python-3.6

so I'm amateur programmer, and I wanted to do something with functions for a little text-based hacking game. In it, a function would be called to allow the player to find the loot and so forth. So I was doing some 'small-scale testing';
 And during my testing, I found that if I had a function (which called a different function inside of it), then some text being 'printed', the second function would be called first.

```
#Example using a sort of 'Decorator'.
def Decor(func):
    print("================")
    print("Hey there")
    print("================")
    print("")
    func

def Hello():
    print("And HELLO WORLD!")

decorated = Decor(Hello())
decorated
```

But the output is always something along the lines of:

```
And HELLO WORLD!
================
Hey there
================
```

Is there a way to make the function be called after the text is printed?
Or simply delay the function being called.
Or am I going about this the wrong way?
Thanks for you time.

Comment: note that `decorated` is `None` and your last statement has no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are passing the result of `Hello()` to `Decor`. This means that `Hello()` will be processed first and then the result will be passed to `Decor` as parameter. What you need is something like this

```
def Decor(func):
    print("================")
    print("Hey there")
    print("================")
    print("")
    func()

def Hello():
    print("And HELLO WORLD!")

decorated = Decor(Hello)
decorated
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the usual approaches to decorate a function in python:

```
def Decor(func):
    def new_func():
        print("================")
        print("Hey there")
        print("================")
        print("")
        func()
    return new_func

def Hello():
    print("And HELLO WORLD!")

decorated = Decor(Hello)
decorated()
```

this way the statements in your `Decor` and `Hello` functions are not called until you call `decorated()`.

you could use the decorator also this way:

```
@Decor
def Hello():
    print("And HELLO WORLD!")

Hello()  # is now the decorated version.
```

there is a [primer on decorators on realpython.com](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/) that might help.